# How to inject template context variable only if it doesn't exist

Tags: django, django-templates, django-context

I have a `base_template.html` that uses a context variable `my_context_var`. All of my other templates extends this base template. Can you help me answer one of these questions? (They are just different ways to look at the same underlying problem)

1. How can I make `my_context_var` available to all the derived templates but allow a way to override `my_context_var` for specific views.
2. How can I inject `my_context_var` into the template context only if that variable is not already there.

Essentially, I'm looking for a setdefaults() functionality for context variables. If it helps, `my_context_var` is basically a blank search form that is available in most pages of my site. I need to override it for one page that displays both the form and the result. The current problem is that I keep getting the blank form even for that result page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options:

You can create your own RequestContext and include all the variables you want through your site: [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

Or you can create template tags and access them in any template: [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)

Comment: looks like template tag is the way to go, at least for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Since it should apply for all of your views the best option is to [create a custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). Templatetags would have the disadvantage that you have to include them everywhere you need this variable. Creating your own `RequestContext` as D.A. stated is overkill in my opinion.

Comment: I tried the context processor route but it seems there isn't a way to inspect the current context and check for the existence of ```my_context_var```

Comment: Can you post the code of your context processor definition? Its hard to get what exactly fails without it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant create a context processor, but be sure to use a RequestContext. My words get crossed sometimes.

Comment: Yes, I understood. Just wanted to see the implementation of your context processor.

Comment: the context processor is really simple:

Comment: the context processor is really simple: ```def dc_simple_search(request):
    return {'simple_search_form': SimpleSearchForm()}``` For most of my pages, this is fine. But for the page that is the form action, I need to render ```{{simple_search_form.fields}``` and it doesn't seem possible because the context processor's version of ```simple_search_form``` always overwrite the view function's version since context_processor is used to update the context after the view function has finished execution

Comment: Ok, now I got your point. I see the problem. A workaround is though to add a variable to the `request` object (like they do with django auth for example, e.g. `request.user`). This one could either indicate if the form is already there or need to be added. Though it is kind of a hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the variable within a template (but only if it doesn't already exist), the following should work:

```
{% with my_context_var=my_context_var|default:"Value you want to set it to" %}
    {# The variable is accessible within then with block #}
    {{ my_context_var }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: This doesn't set `my_context_var` only if it isn't already in the context, it sets it if it's not `True`, which is not the same thing. If `my_context_var` were set to an empty list, for instance, you'd get the default value.